# For loop is not displaying any data in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

incoming json data is displaying in alert but not displaying in html via for loop

[image: Incoming data]

here is the code;

```
                    if(data){
                            alert("hey got the data"+JSON.stringify(data));
                            //for(var i=0; i<arr; i++) {    
                            $.each(data, function(i,element) {
                                  for (var i in element) {
                                    $("#postjson").append(
                                        +'<div id="'abc'">'
                                        +'<p>'
                                        +'FirstName:'+element[i].FirstName+'<br/>'
                                        +'MiddleName:'+element[i].MiddleName+'<br/>'
                                        +'LastName:'+element[i].LastName+'<br/>'
                                        +'Gender:'+element[i].Gender+'<br/>'
                                        +'Location:'+element[i].Location+'<br/>'
                                        +'Email:'+element[i].Email+'<br/>'
                                        +'Mobile:'+element[i].Mobile+'<br/>'
                                        +'</p>'
                                        +'</div>'

                                    );
                                  }
                                });
```

i have tried each function too but it also not displaying data correctly.

Comment: *"not displaying data correctly"* isn't a proper problem description. What is or isn't happening?

Comment: Also please provide sample of data not just  picture of it

Comment: The tag "java" is wrong. Editing to "javascript".

Comment: Are you sure there is an element like `<div id="postjson"/>`?

Comment: yeah, here it is,

   </script>
   
   <div class="grid" id="postjson">
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

I think u have missed an inverted comma after br tag in the line where you are printing "BookTitle:" .

```
                    if(result){
                        alert("hey got the data"+JSON.stringify(result));
                         var arr = result.length;
                         for(var i=0; i<arr; i++) { 
                                $("#postjson").append(  
                                    '<div id="'+result[i].id+'">'
                                    +'<p>'
                                    +'FirstName:'+result[i].data.FirstName+'<br/>'
                                    +'MiddleName:'+result[i].data.MiddleName+'<br/>'
                                    +'LastName:'+result[i].data.LastName+'<br/>'
                                    +'Gender:'+result[i].data.Gender+'<br/>'
                                    +'Location:'+result[i].data.Location+'<br/>'
                                    +'Email:'+result[i].data.Email+'<br/>'
                                    +'Mobile:'+result[i].data.Mobile+'<br/>'
                                    +'BookTitle:'+result[i].data.BookTitle+'<br/>'
                                    +'BookGenre:'+result[i].data.BookGenre+'<br/>'
                                    +'BookWriter:'+result[i].data.BookWriter+'<br/>'
                                    +'Gender:'+result[i].data.BookDescription+'<br/>'
                                    +'</p>'
                                    +'</div>'
                                );
                            }                                           


                           }
                    else {
                        return;             
                    }
```

Comment: please share some sample data on which u are running it... You are giving id as abc have u defined this var ?? also two elements should not have the same id @Cooolranjan

Answer (score 0):

The answer above from @gaurav-gaba appears to be the issue:

```
+'BookTitle:'+result[i].data.BookTitle+'<br/>
```

should be:

```
+'BookTitle:'+result[i].data.BookTitle+'<br/>'
```

The key is the missing single quote after the `<br />`

Comment: yeah, sorry for that. but it's not the issue . even after correcting, i am not able to display the data.